# Get a cached copy of a password-accessed page

Tags: passwords, website, cached-webpages

I'm trying to get a cached copy of this school website: http://moodle.da.org/course/view.php?id=316

I can access the page just fine, but the cached copy redirects to the login timeout site requiring a username and password. If I enter them, I get redirected to the current page instead of its cached one.

Is there a way so that I can get a cached copy of this site?

Answer (score 1):

Google crawlers [do not](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/news/2SdcGEWht1o) access password-accessed page, unless the website has been purposefully designed so (see [Managing crawler access](https://www.google.com/adsense/app#sitepermissions)).

Comment: Ah that's a bummer. :(

Comment: Well it has some downsides and upsides :-)